# jQuery Tokeninput sending back json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jquery-tokeninput

I'm using jQuery Tokeninput to receive categories list. It is looking like this:

```
{id: 1, type: 1, name: "Category1"},
{id: 2, type: 2, name: "Category2"},
{id: 3, type: 1, name: "Category3"},
{id: 4, type: 1, name: "Category4"},
{id: 5, type: 2, name: "Category5"}
```

Then I want to send the selected tokens back to server with ajax, but I can send only array with id OR types OR names. And I need to send the same JSON as I received, same structure and format, but only selected tokens.

I was trying to play with tokenValue parameter, but it want's only 1 parameter, you can not tell him to build JSON.

Comment: do u want to send multiple parameter to the function using tokeninput?

Comment: I'm using tokeninput to make a group of tags inside of a field. And after that, I need to pass selected tags somewhere else. But tokeninput does only the array of IDs. And I need the full JSON of selected items, with name, type and ID.

Comment: but tokeninput output will be always like {"id":"1035","name":"John"},but you need 3 output..it is not supported by the plugin itself

Comment: got the solution for bringing 3 parameters?

Comment: Writing own plugin :(

Comment: if you succeed ..share it ..will be helpful

Comment: I would like to, but due to NDA it will not be mine. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use POST method to send array to server. And send array to server after use JSON.stringify() method on argument.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the problem is in jQuery Tokeninput plugin. After selecting some of categories, it is returning string with IDs (for example "1,4,5"). And I need to pass back the same JSON.

Comment: Use split(",") method to split it in array